# Navbar brand and mobile dropdown on same line bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am currently having trouble getting my logo and the mobile dropdown menu to stay on the same line when the screen size gets below a certain point. I have tried media queries to make the image smaller but am still getting the same issue. I read on another post here to use css to set the nav-bar brand background rather than embedding it with an img tag but when I tried that the image wouldn't show up.

Here is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../../../favicon.ico">

<title>Pristine Clean Outs | Home</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Carousel style-->
<link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Custom Styles-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body id="top">

<header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top bg-white">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img class="img-fluid logo" src="img/pristinelogo.png" alt=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

here is my CSS

```
/* Custom Styles for Pristine Clean by David Jacoby */

nav li {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.carousel-item {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
}

.port-image {
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery_product {
 margin-bottom: 30px;

}

.contact-ul li {
   font-size: 24px;
   list-style-type: none;
}


/* MEDIA QUERIES */

@media (max-width: 768px) { 

.logo {
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}

}
```

Comment: The seem to appear as expected... on one line until the `md` breakpoint https://www.codeply.com/go/K2YfkMBa6N Please clarify the question/issue.

Comment: The logo image i'm using is very wide so when it gets to the smartphone view it pushes the dropdown menu to the next line.

Comment: In order to help, the problem need to be reproducible. Not knowing the size of the image doesn't allow us to repro the issue.

Comment: Once the viewport gets below 552 it moves it to the second line here is it with the actual image.https://www.codeply.com/go/LeGGd5cyBi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wrap the brand and toggler in another flexbox div (`d-flex`) and use `flex-nowrap` to prevent the wrapping...

```
   <div class="d-flex flex-nowrap w-100">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img class="img-fluid logo" src="https://s22.postimg.cc/tf57x6fq9/pristinelogo.png" alt=""></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
   </div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/sVHjLoAyIu

Comment: Thank you so much!